# Possibly fried a new atmega328p?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, atmega328

I have a new atmega328p IC that I wanted to program. To do so I placed it into the socket of an arduino uno. I accidentally placed it the wrong way around (180° rotated), and powered it via USB and tried to upload the blink sketch, which obviously did not succeed. After I noticed it I turned it around and placed it into the socket the right way. I tried again uploading the blink sketch again without success.

1. Have I fried the atmega328p by placing it in the socket the wrong way?
2. Is there something else you need to do to new atmeag328p before you can program them the usual way?

---

**Update:** It seems that just rotating the IC did not damage it in the state where there was no bootloader programmed. And and the bootloader needed to be programmed first before the IC could be used.

Comment: does the new atmega328p have a bootloader programmed?

Comment: @jsotola I don't know, I have no experience with that. Is that something you usually have to do with new ones?

Comment: if the atmega328p is blank, then you could use the Uno as a programmer .... use google to find a tutorial

Comment: @jsotola So is that something that you usually have to do with new atmega328p?

Comment: Chips come blank. It's up to you to put the bootloader on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your chip is fried or not, we can't say, but they're reasonably tough and will stand a bit of abuse before they fail. Did anything smoke or get hot?

You can buy atmega328p chips pre-programmed with a bootloader from a few vendors, but they don't come from the factory that way so most are not. Preprogrammed chips typically cost a couple of $ US more than blank chips for the time spent by the vendor to buy blank ones, program, and repackage them for sale in small quantities, and are almost always advertised as such. If you don't know whether yours is programmed with a bootloader, it probably isn't. It's worth trying to do it yourself, on a breadboard, using a known-working Uno as a bootloader- programmer. There are lots of how-to articles on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It seems that mine did not have a bootloader, and I managed to program it. The basic blink program works so these are two very good signs so far! But I have yet to test all the other pins.

Answer (score 1):

After a reset it should blink pin13 led as all Arduinos do. If not, I'd first try uploading  a bootloader cause I have gotten ones that don't have bootloaders. The 328p if a pretty resistant chip. One time i put 12v into a digital pin and it got so hot the smd desoldered itself but worked fine apart from that pin being blown.

Comment: Thanks, that is very good to know. It seems so far that it did survive my mistake as I managed to program the bootloader!